# getenv()s return None when using Pycharm's Play button

Tags: python, pycharm, python-dotenv

I am using:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getenv
load_dotenv("config/.env")
```

in a project which uses the `pytest` & `selenium` package.

I use `getenv("example_string")` at various points in this file which imports from a `.env` file.

The `getenv()`s work when I run the `pytest` command through the command-line. However, the `getenv()`s all return `None` when I run pytest through Pycharm's 'play button' like in the picture below:

[image]

How can I get the play button to work too?